# ¿Se puede editar un archivo .Java?

Tags: java, java-swing

Necesito modificar unas variables para el arranque de un programa, estas variables son constantes durante el arranque del programa que quiero iniciar, pero a petición del usuario se pueden modificar, estas variables las tengo dentro de un archivo `.java` pero  surge la duda.

¿Puedo editar un archivo `.java` y como se puede editar un archivo `.PROPERTIES` o `.Txt`?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si, el archivo .java lo puedes modificar como modificas cualquier archivo .txt.

Pero hay dos opciones, si lo lees directamente desde tu programa con un FileReader no hay problema ninguno, pero si lo quieres utilizar como parte del programa debes compilarlo en un .class.

Comment: En el caso de los archivos .java son exactamente iguales a los .txt, por lo tanto tendrás que modificar el archivo entero y hacer una búsqueda línea a línea.

Answer (score 1):

Los 3 tipos de archivos que mencionas :

```
.java 
.properties 
.txt
```

los puedes editar con un procesador de texto plano sin problema.

Me parece que lo que deseas es modificar variables dentro de un archivo .java

> Necesito modificar unas variables para el arranque de un programa,
>   estas variables son constantes durante el arranque del programa que
>   quiero iniciar,

Si lo que tienes son constantes y las deseas modificar entonces no debiste definirlas como constantes.

Si al arranque del programa deseas modificar algunas variables estas podrían ser definidas unicamente con el modificador `public` y los valores regularmente se descargan u obtienen de un archivo de configuración, .txt, .json. xml etc.